# How to create private accounts in drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal

I am new in drupal and I want to create :
1. Users with separate roles
2. Users whose profiles are hidden to other users and their profiles can only be viewed by specific people assigned to them.
3. Separate profile view for private accounts